# Only permit traffic to specific domains on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, web-filtering

Three domain-member boxes are sometimes used for proctoring exams. Unfortunately some instructors host their exams on external sites, so blocking all WAN connectivity is not a solution. What software can be used to block all (or possibly just web) traffic except to/from those domains explicitly allowed? The software needs to be easy for test proctors to configure on-demand (i.e. not firewalls), and preferably open source.

Comment: You can easily do this with parental filtering software.  Why don't you just configure the network to only allow access to a whitelist?

Comment: @Ramhound It's much quicker to request software installation than a network infrastructure change.

Comment: Sounds like filtering software that will allow you to setup a whitelist is the way to go.  Its unlikely you will find very many open source solutions or solutions that are easy to configure, so setting it up once is a must.